# How to fix android app resolution on 480*800?

Tags: android, resolution

I saw one android app my galaxy tab(1024*600), it has fixed resolution 800*480.

How to fix my app's resolution like 800*480?

my client wants to fix app resolution..

Comment: Take another shot at explaining what you're after, please.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly define your layout width and height in layout xmls to be 800*480 for all the *un-supported* resolutions like 1024x600.

A list of sample layout folders:

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density

res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density

res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

In case of 3.2 or later, you can define layout files for tablets as well:

res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)

res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

I don't recommend fix your width and height to a specific value but since it's client request, I guess you have to take it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set target sdk version to 1.5 or 1.6. I haven't really tried it yet, but I read somewhere that doing so limits the application to be displayed in a lower resolution.